How can i access the navigation object at a higher level than the components rendered?
I need to pass the navigation object (the one I receive, for example, using useNavigation()) as a prop to a component. The issue is that the one I'm interested in is the navigation object of a nested navigation:
...

export function AddDeviceWizard({navigation}){

const Stack = createStackNavigator(); //Here i create a nested navigator

return (
    <BaseScreen
     navigator={nestedNavigation} //this is te nav i need, not the one who brought me here
     > 
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="addDevice1">
          <Stack.Screen name="addDevice1" component={AddDevice1}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="addDevice2" component={AddDevice2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    <BaseScreen/>

)}

If I use useNavigation(), I'll get the navigation object of the main navigation, the one that brought me to this component. What I'm doing now is a bit tricky, passing the navigation object down through a context from addDevice1 (the first screen that loads), which receives it as a parameter of initialization (... export function AddDevice1({ navigation }) {...}).
Is there any method or property when creating a StackNavigator that allows me to access what I need so that I don't have to grab it in the rendered screens and push it up with a context?

Why do you need it? There might be a better way to solve the actual issue.

BaseScreen has a pressable caret that handles the goBack() method. As this is a reusable component, I need  to know the navigator it needs to use in order to go back to the previous screen. Is there something that I'm missing?

You’re saying if you call ‘useNavigation’ in a child of addDevice1, the navigate function doesnt work as expected?

No, i say that if i call ´useNavigation()´ inside the parent of addDevice1, where i create de the navigator for addDevice1 and addDevice2, there i get the main navigator, not this nested one.
